# Error while reading h5 file in pandas in read mode

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

After having stored the data frame in h5 file i was trying to access the file in another jupyter notebook but when loading the h5 file in read mode in pandas i encountered an error.

I read the file this way

```
data_frames = pd.HDFStore('data_frames.h5', mode='r')
```

Error :

```
HDF5ExtError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.conda/envs/be_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in open(self, mode, **kwargs)
    586         try:
--> 587             self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, self._mode, **kwargs)
    588         except (IOError) as e:  # pragma: no cover

~/.conda/envs/be_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in open_file(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    319     # Finally, create the File instance, and return it
--> 320     return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    321 

~/.conda/envs/be_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
    783         # Now, it is time to initialize the File extension
--> 784         self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
    785 

tables/hdf5extension.pyx in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new (tables/hdf5extension.c:5940)()

HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 604, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1087, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 277, in H5F_super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data_frames.h5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-aa601ba65d4f> in <module>()
----> 1 data_frames = pd.HDFStore('data_frames.h5', mode='r')

~/.conda/envs/be_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in __init__(self, path, mode, complevel, complib, fletcher32, **kwargs)
    446         self._fletcher32 = fletcher32
    447         self._filters = None
--> 448         self.open(mode=mode, **kwargs)
    449 
    450     @property

~/.conda/envs/be_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in open(self, mode, **kwargs)
    617             # is not part of IOError, make it one
    618             if self._mode == 'r' and 'Unable to open/create file' in str(e):
--> 619                 raise IOError(str(e))
    620             raise
    621 

OSError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 604, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1087, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 277, in H5F_super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data_frames.h5'
```

Please help if possible.

Comment: The error message seems to be suggesting that the `data_frames.h5` file is in an invalid format -- "unable to read superblock" and "file signature not found". It would be helpful to see the code which creates `data_frames.h5`. A runnable example which recreates the problem would be even better.

Comment: Yeah just saw that i was trying to store data frame with a column possesing a pandas series as value

Comment: @unutbu How can i store a data frame in a file where a column possess a pandas series like : column A row 1 -> [1,2,3], column A row 2 -> [2,6,9,8], and so on...?

Comment: Pandas HDF5 file support relies on PyTables, and PyTables supports [only certain types of of data](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/datatypes.html): bool, int, uint, float, complex, string, time, enum. In particular, it does not support Python lists. So to store your data in a HDF5 file compatible with Pandas, I would [flatten the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569277/190597) into multiple rows so that there is only one value per row.

Comment: How do you compare storing the data frame as a pickle file or flatten the list and store it as h5 file?